# FindOne by index in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have a mongoose collection that store specific data. and I have an `iduser`. that's name : `var members = new Schema({iduser : {type : String}})`.

```
var member = new members({iduser : req.session.user._id})
```

by the way I have more than one member with the same iduser. and I wanna to find them by index. `member.findOne({iduser})[0]`.

> **I use nodejs for implementation.**

Comment: What do you mean "by index"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every MongoDb Documents have a ObjectId like "612753311aafd14844ec4933"

so You Can find same IdUser with Object Id

```
member.findOne({_id : "OBJECT_ID", idUser :req.session.user._id })
```